# How do I set the glyphimage of a MapKit annotation?

Tags: mapkit, mapkitannotation

I know this is basic stuff but the documentation online is thin. I am new to Apple Mapkit and I am trying to create a simple annotation with a `glyphImage` overlay. I have the annotation working, but when I try to set the `glyphImage` the map blows up. The code I am using is:

```
testAnnotation.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "/public/img/site/tester.png");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is "/public/img/site/tester.png" ?

Comment: If you use Asset Catalog, you can write `UIImage(named: "tester")`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out:

```
var testAnnotation = new MarkerAnnotation(test, {
        title: "This is a Test!",
        subtitle: "Testing Apple MapKit",
        glyphImage: {
                1: "/images/testimage.png"
            }
        });
```

Comment: This was 100% the answer for my javascript implementation. Spent 3 hours digging and this is what worked. Many Thanks!